# MySQL: List students (Sname) who enrolled in more than 6 (distinct) classes in a term

Tags: mysql, select, count

Given the schema:

```
Student(Snum, Sname)
Course(Cnum, Cname)
Prerequisite(Cnum, Prereq)
Professor(Pnum,Pname, Dept, Office)
Enrollment(Snum, Cnum, Term, Section, Mark)
Schedule(Cnum, Term, Section, Days, Time, Room)
Class(Cnum, Term, Section, Instructor)
```

I have come up with:

```
SELECT * FROM Student s
HAVING MIN(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Enrollment e
    WHERE e.Snum = s.Snum
    GROUP BY e.Term
) > 6
```

But I am getting:

> /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Enrollment
>   e  WHERE e.Snum = s.Snum  GROUP BY
>   e.Term ) >' at line 3 */

Any idea as to how I can fix this? Thanks!

Also, it would be reassuring to know that I have the right logic =)

EDIT: FINAL ANSWER...

```
SELECT Student.Sname
FROM(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Cnum) as `classes`, e.Term as `term`, e.Snum as `student`
    FROM Enrollment e
    GROUP BY e.Term, e.Snum
) x
JOIN Student ON Student.Snum = `student`
WHERE x.`classes` > 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see students that had at least 6 classes in **each** term:

```
SELECT * FROM Student s
WHERE (SELECT MIN(perTerm) FROM(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Cnum) as perTerm FROM Enrollment e
    WHERE e.Snum = s.Snum
    GROUP BY e.Term
)) > 6
```

Here you go. You were almost there, but `HAVING` cannot be used if you don't have a `GROUP BY`.

If you want **any** term replace `MIN` with `MAX` and if you want a specific term use the updated version of Vegard.

---

If the double subquery doesn't work try this one:

```
SELECT `student`
FROM(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Cnum) as `classes`, s.Term as `term`, s.Snum as `student`
    FROM Enrollment e
    GROUP BY e.Term, e.Snum
)
GROUP BY `term`
HAVING MIN(`classes`) > 6
```

Comment: after adding 'x' after the from, because it requires an alias, i get: "/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 's.Snum' in 'where clause' */"

Comment: Thanks! Edited a bit (like removing min and changing to where) as well as selecting the Sname in the end for what I needed. You rock!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Student s
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Enrollment e
    WHERE e.Snum = s.Snum
    AND e.Term = <some term>
) > 6
```

No need to use an aggregate function here, so use a normal `WHERE` (not `HAVING`) for the subquery as well.

Edit: modified to only check one term at a time. If you absolutely need to check all terms, I don't immediately have a good idea.

Comment: Pay attention. The subquery will return a set not a single item. You also need to compute the MIN of that set.

Comment: yes, i need to check every term until i find 1 or none for every student with >6 classes